Translation from dialects: off-topic?
Background:
I started studying Chinese on my own about 2 years ago. My method was to learn enough grammar to translate and then translate many things. Due to lack of time, and also to make finding the translation exercises easy, I decided to translate songs randomly gotten off Youtube. So I bumped into a few songs in Min, Cantonese and Hakka.
Question:
If I ask a translation question on one of these, should I expect it to be closed as off-topic because they are about dialects, or should I expect an answer as if it were a translation question about something in Mandarin?

I personally encourage questions about dialects. Dialects are much richer than mandarin. Many great poets spoke dialects, their poems don't rhyme at all in mandarin. I didn't realize this until I came to contact with people whose spoke dialects. There are also a lot proverbs in dialects that have no trace in mandarin.

According to the Help Topic on "What topics can I ask", there is no distinction made for dialects. Translation is supported under certain conditions. The criteria includes showing prior work and making sure that the question is specific (has a definitive answer) rather than open-ended (discussion based). Additional insight can be gathered from this question.


Just for curiosity: is there a site where I could ask a hypothetical culture question without it being considered off-topic?

@MickG As long as the eventual question is about language, I think you should preface your question with some background about the cultural aspect of the language question and use this site. Just be sure there is a valid language question at the end. People may comment on the cultural aspects if the language question is interesting enough.

@MickG Agreed with Tommie. You can also: ask on Meta for advice whether the question fits the site guidelines, or you can ask in our Chat. :) There is no "off topic" there.
